# What are windows .cmd files called?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

While .bat files are referred to as batch (I assume because the extension starts with **bat**) files, I've sort of always called cmd files batch files too.

Is that the proper term for them?
What are they called? I've never heard anyone say, "Make a command file." I've just heard people say "make a batch file," or "make a cmd file."

Comment: A "batch file" or "Cmd shell script". What's provoking the question?

Comment: I'm writing a developer guide on using it and I need to make sure they use CMD files, so I needed to know if I needed to reference them differently.

Comment: Not sure why people down voted or voted to close. I checked and there are a ton of other questions about terminology related to scripting and programming.

Comment: I guess you can't go wrong describing them as "Windows Command" files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Filename_extensions) these are still called batch files; the following outlines the primary difference between the two.

> In addition, "set", "path", "assoc" and "prompt" commands, when executed from a .bat file, alter the value of the "errorlevel" variable only upon an error, whereas from within a .cmd file, they would affect errorlevel even when returning without an error.

*Batch File* may refer to a script with any of the following three extensions: `.bat`, `.cmd`, `.btm`

Comment: Are you sure about the .btm ? Does this work with a standard Windows or does it need some extension software ?

Comment: .btm files are from 4DOS, a shell you could use to replace the MS-DOS COMMAND.COM used in CONFIG.SYS. That I know ;)

Comment: How would you differentiate the two types though when talking about them? Because .cmd and .bat files operate differently, for example error code handling.

Comment: @Thraka: on the rare occasion when the distinction is important, I would say "dot bat" and "dot cee emm dee".